# Get access to the same randomized String as in other class

Tags: java, random

Stupid question about Java basics, but I cannot beat it for days already.

I have a class with initialized data. Randomizer is here.

```
public class AddContract {
    private Data data = new Data();

    class Data {
        final String CONNUM = String.valueOf(randInt());

        public int randInt() {
            int min = 1;
            int max = 7777;
            return (int) (Math.random() * max + min);
        }
    }
```

And I have another class:

```
public class ContractsPage {

    public ContractsPage FindContractByContractNumber() {
       AddContract.Data buffer = new AddContract.Data();
       this.contractNumberFilter.clear();
       this.contractNumberFilter.sendKeys(buffer.CONNUM);
           return this;
    }
}
```

Pls don't judge how it looks now coz I was trying many variants how to make it work.
So, I want get the same instanse of randInt in class `ContractsPage` as it is in class `AddContract`. But Object through `new` generates "new" rng.

tl;dr:
With random I get var=5 in Class1, I want to adress the same var=5 in Class2.

Comment: Your design looks *really* weird, and I can't possibly understand what you're saying. You want to address "the same var=5" in Class2? Why does your `Data` class call methods in its parent class which calls a method in the `Data` class? What on earth are you trying to do?

Comment: On `AddContract` you do just return a string of the random value. You´re not saving it. Every call will return a other one. So can you please clarify little bit more.

Comment: @LenglBoy you just said what I want to do. "Do not return a other one". But the same one.

Answer (score 0):

do the random oprtaions in constructor of the class and keep it in an instance variable.

```
public class AddContract {
    private Data data = new Data();
    private String bufferCONNUMStr = String.valueOf(data.randInt());

    public String bufferCONNUM() {
        return bufferCONNUMStr;
    }

}
```

Comment: After that I could not sendKeys since not a String. Fixed with static method. Now num generates same rng() in class AddContract but when I initialize Object in ContractsPage by this variable it's a whole new rng().

static class bufferCONNUM {
        int min;
        int max;
        int rng;
        bufferCONNUM() {
            min = 1;
            max = 7777;
            rng = (int) (Math.random() * max + min);
        }
        final String rng() {
            return String.valueOf(rng);
        }
    }
bufferCONNUM num = new bufferCONNUM();
        String nums = num.rng();

Answer (score 0):

```
public class AddContract {
    private Data data = new Data();

    public String bufferCONNUM() {
        return data.CONNUM;
    }
    public String bufferPURCHNUM() {
        return data.PURCHASENUM;
    }

    class Data {
        final String CONNUM = String.valueOf(randInt());
        final String PURCHASENUM = String.valueOf(randInt());

        public final int randInt() {
            int min = 1;
            int max = 7777;
            return (int) (Math.random() * max + min);
        }
    }
}
```